# Add Ansible-Server where Ansible is hosted to hosts

Tags: ansible

Is there a possibility to add the server, where Ansible is running to the hostfile and maintain it also through Ansible playbooks?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [implicit `localhost`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory/implicit_localhost.html) using the [`local` connection plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/local_connection.html) is available by default. Meanwhile it does not match the `all` group (nor any other actually).

So you can either:

- target it explicitly in your play, e.g. `hosts: host_a:group_b:localhost`
- define it explicitly in your inventory so it matches the `all` group if you use it, e.g. (ini format) `localhost ansible_connection=local`

Note that the second option can work with any symbolic name you decide to use e.g. `my.host.local ansible_connection=local`

Comment: That is the answer - thank you very much! Had to add my pubkey to the authorized keys on the same machine, but now it works smoothly.

Comment: Note: you should not have to add any key when using the `local` connection plugin. Ansible just spawns a new shell on your local machine in that case.